# Jersey @Path for plural/single REST nouns in same class

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a class this is annotated with `@Path` like so:

```
@Path("widgets")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class WidgetResource {

    @GET
    public Response getWidgets(@QueryParam("limit"))
    {
     //This class returns the plural noun, a list of widgets
    //...}

@GET
@Path("widget/{id}")
    public Response getWidgetById(@PathParam("id") long id)
    {
     //This class returns a single widget by id
    //...}
```

When I fire up a test client the localhost/widgets maps as expected, but when the `getWidgetById` method is mapped to `localhost/widgets/widget/{id}`. This is not what I want - I would like to have `localhost/widgets and localhost/widget/{id}`

I have tried omitting the `@Path` annotation at the class level, but that prevents Jersey from recognizing this class as a REST Resource (I tried both the `ScanningResourceConfig` and the `ClassNameResourceConfig` - both failed to load the class as a resource unless there was a `@Path` at the class level).

I guess a (ugly) workaround would be to split the methods between classes a `WidgetResource` class and a `WidgetsResource` class. I think this is a terrible solution since both of these methods share resources in the same class, but I really need the REST-ful `localhost/widget` (for a single entity) and `localhost/widgets` (for plural).

Am I missing something - is there some way for me to have Jersey pick up the class as a Resource class if I just `@Path` annotate the methods (I couldn't get it to work), if not can I force absolute mapping (`@Path(/widget/{id})`) or some relative mapping (`@Path(../widget/id`) - neither of those work in reality - just an analogy of what I'm after. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**This part is about what you *need*:**

Personally, I find your mapping strange and confusing. Just keep it like this:

```
@Path("widgets")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class WidgetResource {

  @GET
  public Response getWidgets(@QueryParam("limit")) {
   //This method returns the plural noun, a list of widgets
   // it's also possible to limit the number returned by
   // using a query parameter. You could easily implement
   // pagination by adding further query parameters like
   // 'offset', 'sortOrder', etc.
   //...
  }

  @GET
  @Path("{id}")
  public Response getWidgetById(@PathParam("id") long id) {
    //This method returns a single widget by id
    //...
  }
}
```

It seems natural to append the path to a collection with an ID to fetch an object from the collection. There's really no need to make it `widgets/widget/{id}`. The `widget` part is obvious and unnecessary.

Here's a really neat  tutorial on RESTful APIs:  ["Teach a dog to REST" by apigee](http://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design/) I think it's a really good video. The authors make a couple of good points. And here's a link to a [longer version of the same presentation](http://blog.apigee.com/detail/slides_for_restful_api_design_second_edition_webinar)

---

**This part is about what you *want*:**

If you really want to keep the plural/singular dualism (which I really don't recomment), you can annotate your code like this:
**But it's really ugly**

```
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class WidgetResource {

  @GET
  @Path("widgets")
  public Response getWidgets(@QueryParam("limit")) {
   //This method returns the plural noun, a list of widgets
  //...}

  @GET
  @Path("widget/{id}")
  public Response getWidgetById(@PathParam("id") long id) {
    //This method returns a single widget by id
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I got the widget / widgets thing from the video, but it sounds like I might be remembering it wrong - in either case it's part of our API, but we can change it if there is a good case. I'm going to consult with the team and go with one of the approaches above. Thanks!

Comment: @cschooley that's funny, I don't remember anything like this. I guess I'll watch it again myself.

Comment: We designed our API to have a singular plural pair of URLs like this (this is the long version) (plural stuff starts at starts at 11:00): http://blog.apigee.com/detail/slides_for_restful_api_design_second_edition_webinar

Comment: But around 15:29 appears to slightly contradict and recommend plurals in all situations e.g. "checkins/1234". Hmmm.

Comment: @cschooley actually, the speaker (Brian Mulloy) strongly contradicts using such pairs at 14:25. He advises to choose either plural, or singular. But not both. I'll ad a link to the longer video to my answer anyway.

Comment: In case anybody is still reading we opted for always using the plural "widgets" and "widgets/123" since it's obvious from the context which is singular and plural and it makes the API smaller and less error prone. As a bonus cleaner in Jersey to implement.

Comment: Having multiple URIs to access to the same resource is not bad, so IMHO widget and widgets paths are OK (from /widget you can access to the widget resource directly from root, and on /widgets case, you can navigate to the same resource but from a collection of widgets)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to have your paths be:
`"widgets"` and `"widgets/id/{id}"`. Or if you knew you were never going to query by anything other than id, your second one could simply be `"widgets/{id}"`.

I would not switch between plural and singular in your path.  Since you accessing the same type of resource for both, your root should be the same.  The second form just specifies it more -- a vectoring-based approach for getting more specific.